# Why does a projection is considered as a disc and calculated by this way?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have been reading a scientific paper that illustrate a projection method as follow

${F^2} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{f_1}:{x_1}^3 + {x_2}^2 + {x_1}{x_2} - \frac{1}{2}} \\ 
  {{f_2}:{x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 - 2} 
\end{array}} \right.$

Define the projection order ${x_1} \prec {x_2}$ the projection is $\left( {{x_1},{x_2}} \right) \mapsto {x_1}$.

1/ Why does a projection is considered as a disc and is calculated by this way ?

2/ How to visualize or at least understand the meaning of $lc\left( {{f_2},{x_2}} \right)$ and $res\left( {{f_1},{f_2},{x_2}} \right)$ ?

Please help me understand this !
Thank you !
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to question 2):

lc(f,x), means "**L**eading **C**oefficient" (coefficient of monomial in $f$ having the highest degree with repect to variable $x$ ).

Besides, the computations re linked to **Res**ultants of two polynomials $Res_x(f,g)$ (denoted here  $Res(f,g,x)$), a particular case being the **Disc**riminant of a polynomial:

$$Disc_x(f)=Res_x(f,f')$$

where $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$ with respect to variable $x$.

All this and the way to compute a resultant using a determinant can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

This said, there is a simpler (classical) way to compute discriminants in this case. Indeed, polynomial $f_1$, considered as a quadratic in variable $x_2$;

$$x_2^2 +x_1x_2 + (x_1^3-\frac12)$$

has **disc**riminant (in the usual sense)

$$\Delta= x_1^2-4(x_1^3-\frac12)=2+x_1^2-4x_1^3$$

Same kind of computation for $f_2$...

Comment: I advise you the reading of Milne's Course notes [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG510.pdf). In particular the notion of resultant, and more generally to elimination theory, is to be found around p. 127.

Comment: Thank you, may I ask what kind of branch of mathematics does these things belong too. I hope to receive some suggestions for reading material. I hope you could suggest something that is easy to read for engineer, those who did not have mathematics rigor.

Comment: A first answer: the corresponding branch of mathematics is algebraic geometry. I will look for documents that are more accessible.

Comment: Maybe, you should say what you are interested in because this issue is so particular that I cannot infer from it the domain in which you work. Ffor example why are you interested in a "projection method" ["forgetting" $f_1$ gives $f_2=x_1^2+x_2^2-2$ which is the equation of a circle, but there is surely something more in your quest] ?

Comment: Thank you, I am interested in something called Algebraic Cylindrical Decomposition (CAD). This is only the projection phase of the algorithm, there is also lifting phase but that is out of the scope of this stack exchange question

Comment: I can advise you this book: 
Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry, Springer, 2016, by Saugata Basu, Richard Pollack, Marie-Francoise Roy,

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help !

Comment: You can find it online [here](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted3.pdf)